# Can't store session in MongoDB with passport

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm new to Node JS and I'm trying to store session in mongoDB by using the connect-mongo npm package , once I add the following line - i get an error :

```
app.use(session({
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true,
  store   : new MongoStore({ // adding this will cause an error
  db: 'users'
 })
}));
```

[image: Error]

Here are the session parts of my code (i'm using express 4.16) :

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var session = require('express-session');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
    var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
    var multer = require('multer');
    var upload = multer({dest: './uploads'});
    var flash = require('connect-flash');
    var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
    var mongo = require('mongodb');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var MongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(session);
    var db = mongoose.connection;
    session(app, mongo.initSessionStore);

   app.use(session({
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true,
      store   : new MongoStore({
        db: 'users'
      })
    }));

    // Passport
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't sent instance of MonogDB to `MongoStore`. You sent string `'user'`, and it expect database instance. So it can't connect to MonogDB.

If you are using Mongoose you need first to connect to database, and then you can use`mongoose.connection` for MongoStore:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

app.use(session({
      saveUninitialized: true,
      resave: true,
      store   : new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db
      })
}));
```